# Text in Gridview longer than width

Tags: asp.net, gridview, width

that the text in the gridview is longer than the width of the table. You can see how it looks here: [Link](http://fahrschule-r%C3%BCegg.ch/Gaestebuch.aspx) 
Does anybody know how i can fix this? 
My code looks so:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="tabEintraege" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" DataSourceID="dbGaestebuch" Width="598px" ShowHeader="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:200px;"><b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Nachname") %></b></td>
                        <td style="width:200px;" rowspan="2"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Nachricht") %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Datum","{0:D}")%></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width in the `<table>`.

Comment: Where? I have try set a fixed width in "<asp:GridView>", "<table>" and "<td>". Nothing has an effect... thx

Comment: and the cell in the next row needs to have columnspan="2"

Comment: This has no effect. The Text goes over the define width of the table :-( -> [link](http://fahrschule-rüegg.ch/Gaestebuch.aspx). Is there maybe a option in asp:GridView for activate automatic break?

Comment: Looks like you have nested ".inner" classes - try setting a width on this container?

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't work at this time, so I am just guessing your problem is about wrapping the text.

Did you try `nowrap` attribute or its CSS version?

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_td_nowrap.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_nowrap_css

Keep in mind that nowrap attribute has been deprecated.